# Parse error:syntax error

Tags: errors, troubleshooting

I'm new to Wordpress. I'm trying to create a Wordpress theme.
But i am getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'meta' (T_STRING) in \xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme\index.php on line 31
```

Error File **Index.php**

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
    <?php /* The Loop — with comments! */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

<?php /* Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() */ ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php /* an h2 title */ ?>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php /* Microformatted, translatable post meta */ ?>
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
                        <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
                        <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                        <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date"><?php _e('Published ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
                        <span class="entry-date"><abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-dTH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></abbr></span>
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), '<span class="meta-sep">|</span><span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php /* The entry content */ ?>
                    <div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&amp;raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )  ); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'your-theme' ) . '&amp;after=</div>') ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                    <?php /* Microformatted category and tag links along with a comments link */ ?>
                    <div class="entry-utility">
                        <span class="cat-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links"><?php _e( 'Posted in ', 'your-theme' ); ?></span><?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></span>
                        <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                        <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>" ) ?>
                        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ) ) ?></span>
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), '<span class="meta-sep">|</span><span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- #entry-utility -->
                </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php /* Close up the post div and then end the loop with endwhile */ ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #container -->

<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
</div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
</div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes outside of the following statement, why you are getting this error because you are using double quotes for class attribute `"</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>"` and also wrapping it in double quotes.

replace this

`"</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>"`

with

`'</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>'`

or vice versa

`"</span><span class='meta-sep'>|</span>"`

```
<?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ', ', '</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>' ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead on line 31, your quotes are not consistent:

```
<?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ', ', '</span><span class="meta-sep">|</span>' ) ?>
```